# Jack audio kit API thread synchronization

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, jack

Jack kit API uses a callback from its (real-time) thread for processing audio data:

```
jack_set_process_callback (client, process, 0);
...

int process(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
    ...
}
```

How can I thread-safely transmit some parameters to this callback (without blocking operations, of course)? I don't need only to transmit parameters, but also to re-initialize audio filtering object, therefore I need to find event-based solution.

Comment: I don't need only to transmit parameters, but also to re-initialize audio filtering object, therefore I need to find event-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate your event in your main thread and send a pointer to that event to your audio thread using a ringbuffer (jack/ringbuffer.h).  Use a second ringbuffer to send the pointer back to your main thread so you can free the memory.

There's a good, simple example at http://harryhaaren.blogspot.com/2011/11/tutorial-jack-ringbuffers.html